# What does (0 << 12) mean in Swift?

Tags: swift, bit-shift

In the docs I found an enum case defined as:

```
kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault = (0 << 12)
```

As far as I know, this means bit shift zero 12 times... which is still zero. What am I missing?

Comment: for a second I was like what is is "bit-sh**"? :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [Apple Doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgbitmapinfo?language=objc) for `CGBitmapInfo`:

> The byte order constants specify the byte ordering of pixel formats.
>
> ...If the code is not written correctly, it’s possible to misread the data which leads to colors or alpha that appear wrong.

The various constants for `kCGBitmapByteOrder` mostly map to similarly named constants in `CGImageByteOrder`, which does not have a "Default."

Those values are found in detail [in the docs for `CGImageByteOrderInfo`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgimagebyteorderinfo?language=objc)

The one you asked about is the default, which as you noted bit-shifts 0, which is still 0, but as Rob notes the preceding/following bits still matter.

What you were missing is the other options:

`kCGBitmapByteOrder16Little = (1 << 12)` 
16-bit, little endian format.

`kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little = (2 << 12)`
32-bit, little endian format.

`kCGBitmapByteOrder16Big = (3 << 12)`
16-bit, big endian format.

`kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big = (4 << 12)`
32-bit, big endian format.

These use different values depending on 16-bit vs 32-bit image, and whether you care about the least or most-significant digit first.

The "Default" `(0 << 12)` follows the same format/process of shifting by 12. And, as Rob pointed out, the the first 12 bits and any following also have meaning. Using these other options has a different effect in how they're interpreted vs using the "Default"

Answer (score 6):

If you look at all of the relevant values, you see:

```
kCGBitmapByteOrderMask     = kCGImageByteOrderMask,
kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault  = (0 << 12),
kCGBitmapByteOrder16Little = kCGImageByteOrder16Little,
kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little = kCGImageByteOrder32Little,
kCGBitmapByteOrder16Big    = kCGImageByteOrder16Big,
kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big    = kCGImageByteOrder32Big
```

And `kCGBitmapByteOrderMask` is `0x7000` (i.e. the three bits after you shift over 12 bits; `0b0111000000000000`).

So `0 << 12` is just a very explicit way of saying "if the bits, after you shift over 12 bits, are 0". Yes, `0 << 12` is actually `0`, but it's making it explicit that `kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault` is not when the whole `CGBitmapInfo` value is zero (because there could be other meaningful, non-zero, data in those first 12 bits), but only when the bits after the first 12 are zero.

So, in short, the `<< 12` is not technically necessary, but makes the intent more explicit.

Answer (score 0):

A construct like that is meant as either a place holder or documentation of a no-longer-supported feature. It means that including the value `kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault` in a summation will yield the same value; hence it is only for documentation.